# Do we need the [downtime] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I can not see any possible use for the [downtime](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/downtime) tag, and there are only 7 questions tagged with it. Should we remove it?

Comment: [tag:downtime] is now clear.

Comment: @ṧнʊß Cheers and thanks!